# How to get html content of a page after navigating to it in Playwright ? Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, playwright

I am visiting a website and navigating to a new page from there. I want html of that page but I am getting the html of old page with page. content().
Can anyone help me out.

```
 with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://www.espncricinfo.com/", timeout=0)
        page.locator("div[role=\"tooltip\"] >> text=Rankings").click()
        page.wait_for_url("https://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211271.html")
        html = page.content()
        context.close()
        
        browser.close()
```

Comment: Sure that `div[role=\"tooltip\"] >> text=Rankings` is being found and clicked? Cannot find an element with such locator on that page.

Comment: locator ensures the presence of the element before clicking it so It is not possible that URL is not clicked